# Google Chrome and apache .htaccess redirect loop error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, https

I have a problem that only affects google chrome. I have two subdirectories secure.fixnode.ca and storage.fixnode.ca, both of these sudirectories need to use https protocol.

The error I get in Google Chrome is: "Redirect Loop Error, Too Many Redirects"

**storage.fixnode.ca** works OK in google chrome, but for some reason **secure.fixnode.ca** does NOT.

Also **BOTH** subdirectories work great in every other browser (IE, FF, Safari).

below is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fixnode\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.fixnode.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(secure|storage)\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# END OF CHANGE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 401 /?loc=401error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /?loc=404error.php

Options -Indexes
```

The line that is giveing me trouble is:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

it seems that google chrome sees apache https redirects as a redirect error.

does anyone know if I can do this any other way that will work in google chrome and other browsers?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Phillip K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your situation it seems your https redirect goes into an infinite redirect loop. I've reason to believe the %{HTTPS} variable isn't as stable is it should be (I've seen other people have had problems with this).

Try to change the %{HTTPS} condition from:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

**to:**

```
# If not port 443 (https) then this condition should match
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
```

Alernatives are:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
```

and..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ^http$
```

Comment: ok, works fine. but how safe is it to rely on the port or request scheme?